# How to show if a database is ACID or BASE?

Tags: database, database-design, database-development

I was wondering if there are general guides or standards which can be followed when trying to show if your own database implementation is [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) or [BASE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency) compliant?

For example are there any specific tests I can run?

Comment: By reading the documentation or doing a Google search.  For example, Googling ["Is MongoDB Acid"](https://www.google.com/search?q=is+mongodb+acid) yields ["MongoDB is not ACID compliant."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149890/what-does-mongodb-not-being-acid-compliant-really-mean)

Comment: @RobertHarvey I should specify that I am building my own DB from the ground up so the question is more along the lines of **how** you can test if your own database implementation is or isn't ACID or BASE compliant.

Comment: Perhaps have a look at the SQLite source?  The testing code for SQLite is 10x the size of the actual SQLite code.  There's almost certainly some ACID tests in there somewhere.

Comment: Of course, if there are such tests, they demand to be named LITMUS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The design of an ACID database is significantly different from that of a BASE database.  ACID gives you assurances that a transaction will be complete.  Distributing an ACID database adds significant complexity.  BASE and other non-ACID databases are simpler to build and test.

Concepts to test (choose according to ACID / BASE design):

- Is is possible to see part of a transaction change? (Depends on isolation level.)
- Do changes appear in order?
- Is the database view consistent with the effective isolation level?  (Effective isolation level may not be the requested level.)
- Do committed transaction survive a restart?
- Do committed transactions survive a database crash?
- Can a transaction be rolled back?
- Is the appropriate data returned after a rollback?
- Do uncommitted transactions survive a database crash or restart? (Fail case)
- Can a record with an uncommitted change be updated by anoouther transaction?
- Are conflicting changes handled appropriately?
- Are results appropriate is changes have not converged?
- What happens if one instance of a distributed database instance shuts down (crash or requested)?
- What happens when a distributed database instance rejoins the cluster?
- What happens if a distributed database instance never rejoins the cluster?

Your expectations are for these concepts will drive the type of database you build.